# List that keeps track of the iteration of characters in a string

Tags: python, list, iteration, encoder

I am writing an encoder, and I want to keep a list that keeps track of the iteration of characters in a string.

For example:

```
Input = aaabccccaa
Output = [3, 1, 4, 2]
```

This is what I have:

```
def numberCheck(string, numberList):
    teller = 1
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1,len(string)):
            if string[i] == string[j]:
                teller += 1
            else:
                break
        numberList.append(teller)
        teller = 1
    return numberList
```

But this gives me as output `[3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1]`

I know why this is the output, but I don't know how to fix in the code so that I have the output that I want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a new loop for each letter, just reset the counter to 1 in your outer loop.  Also, you shouldn't pass the number list to the function; it should define its own:

```
def numberCheck(string):
    if not string:
        return []
    numberList = []
    current = string[0]
    i = 0 
    for char in string:
        if char == current:
            i += 1
        else:
            current = char
            numberList.append(i)
            i = 1 
    numberList.append(i)
    return numberList
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser! I like your method, it's clever and simple.

Comment: @AggonyAchilles: I'm glad you like it.  If you know which answer helped you most, please consider accepting it by clicking the gray check mark below its vote count.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for this task (specifically, [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)), instead of the long function you have.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> Input = "aaabccccaa"
>>> [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(Input)]
[3, 1, 4, 2]
```

And if you want to keep the letter, its count and its order of appearance in the string:

```
>>> [{k: len(list(group))} for key, group in groupby(Input)]
[{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {'c': 4}, {'a': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Andy has the "right" answer meaning that it's concise and easy to read. If you care about time, this is about 25% faster.

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "aaabccccaa"
print [sum(1 for _ in group) for _, group in groupby(string)]
# [3, 1, 4, 2]
```

If you *really* care about time, the zondo's solution is 50% faster than that. Approximate benchmarks for 10,000 runs:

```
me:    543 ms
andy:  746 ms
zondo: 286 ms
```

This was done on Python 2.7.

**Edit:** It looks like Andy's version is faster on Python 3.4:

```
me:    611
andy:  461
zondo: 254
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop starts the inner loop at each character.  You need your outer loop to move forward to the next block of different characters, not the next one.

To fix this, with the same algorithm, use a `while` loop so that you can adjust how much you advance the loop control variable `i`:

```
def numberCheck(string):
    numberList = []
    teller = 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        for j in range(i + 1,len(string)):
            if string[i] == string[j]:
                teller += 1
            else:
                break
        numberList.append(teller)
        i += teller  # advance by the number of characters you just counted
        teller = 1
    return numberList
```

Alternatively use just one loop and a condition (with some local variables) to determine when to do something different.  *(update: see zondo's answer for this code)*

*(I am being descriptive rather than providing code since this appears to be a homework problem)*

Comment: Okay, in that case: see zondo's answer.  It is what I was suggesting in my second recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I completely forgot you can actually control the outer loop with a while function.